# Python pandas generate excel file with 1000 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have one excel file with 38 000 rows. I would like an excel file to be created after every 1000 rows. At the end I should have 38 excel files. This is my very simple script in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import deepl

WD = r'C:\Users\Admin\XXX\\'

for file in os.listdir(WD):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        FILE = file

        sheet_names = pd.ExcelFile(FILE).sheet_names  

        for sn in sheet_names:
            OUTPUT_FILE = '{}_{}'
            df = pd.read_excel(FILE)
            print(FILE, sn)

            for col in df.columns.to_list():
                df[col] = df[col].map({True: '', False: ''}).fillna(df[col])

            auth_key = 'XX'
            translator = deepl.Translator(auth_key)
        

            df['TRANSLATE'] = df['COLUMN TO TRANSLATE'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate_text(x,  
               target_lang="CS") if type(x) == str else x)


        cn = ['COLUMN TO TRANSLATE', 'TRANSLATE']
        df = df.reindex(columns = cn)

        df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Admin\\FINAL_FILE.xlsx', index=False)
```

Have you any Idea?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by helper array by [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with integer division by `N`:

```
N = 1000
for val, df1 in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // N):
     df1.to_excel(rf'C:\Users\Admin\\FINAL_FILE_{val}.xlsx', index=False)
```

EDIT: For processing by 1000 rows use:

```
for file in os.listdir(WD):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        FILE = file

        sheet_names = pd.ExcelFile(FILE).sheet_names  

        for sn in sheet_names:
            OUTPUT_FILE = '{}_{}'
            df = pd.read_excel(FILE)
            print(FILE, sn)
            
            for val, df1 in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // N):

                for col in df1.columns.to_list():
                    df1[col] = df1[col].map({True: '', False: ''}).fillna(df1[col])
    
                auth_key = 'XX'
                translator = deepl.Translator(auth_key)
            
    
                df1['TRANSLATE'] = df1['COLUMN TO TRANSLATE'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate_text(x,  
                   target_lang="CS") if type(x) == str else x)
    
    
                cn = ['COLUMN TO TRANSLATE', 'TRANSLATE']
                df1 = df1.reindex(columns = cn)
        
                df1.to_excel(rf'C:\Users\Admin\\FINAL_FILE_{val}.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have one more question. Because my script translates using online API which is not free. Sometimes it happens that the internet goes out or some error occurs and my srcipt gets killed. Then I have no file and have to pay again for the same translation. Is it possible for the file to be generated immediately after its creation? So the 38 files are created one after the other?

Comment: @HEV - I think it will working exactly like need. Immediatly after filled `df` are genereated excel files.

Comment: I am trying this solution on test data and all files were generated only after the script completed successfully.

Comment: @HEV - what is exception if error occurs ?

Comment: There is no error, script run right but the 38 files are generated after the script is all completed

Comment: @HEV - So need processing each 1000 rows? Answer is edited. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it's this script that solved my problem :-). But thank you @jezrael for your help:

```
auth_key = 'xxx'
translator = deepl.Translator(auth_key)

FILE = r"XXX\File.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(FILE)
nor = df.shape[0]
breakpoint = 0
chunk_size = 1000

iteration_number = int(round(nor/chunk_size))
for y in range(0,iteration_number+1):
    
    df1 = df.iloc[breakpoint:breakpoint+chunk_size,:]

    if df1.empty == False:
       # print(df1)

        df1['TRANSLATE'] = df1['COLUMN TO TRANSLATE'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate_text(x, target_lang="CS") if type(x) == str else x)

        cn = ['COLUMN TO TRANSLATE', 'TRANSLATE']
        df1 = df1.reindex(columns = cn)
        df1.to_excel(rf'C:\Users\Admin\\FINAL_FILE_{val}.xlsx', index=False)

    breakpoint = breakpoint+chunk_size
```